# Sorting a 2d string array based on user input?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, sorting

I'm pretty new to programming and recently I received a school assignment in which I need to sort a 2D array. Basically the program needs to receive various names from the user and print them out the original, descending, and ascending order. Here's the code I have so far: the button that accepts the values, and the button that prints the original work but I'm having trouble sorting the input. As you will probably see in the ascending button I tried to use `Array.Sort` but realized it only works for 1D arrays and I don't really know what else to try.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  string[,] matrizN = new string[3,3];
  int n = 0;
  int m = 0;
  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void btn_Acpt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (n < 3) {
      if (m < 3) {
        matrizN[n, m] = txt_Val.Text;
        m++;
      } else {
        m = 0;
        n++;
        matrizN[n, m] = txt_Val.Text;
      }
      txt_Val.Clear();
      txt_Val.Focus();
    } else {
      MessageBox.Show("Limit 9 names");
    }
  }

  private void btn_Ori_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        MessageBox.Show(matrizN[x, y].ToString());
      }
    }
  }

  private void btn_Asc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Array.Sort(matrizN);
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        MessageBox.Show(matrizN[x, y].ToString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All help is appreciated, but I would prefer it if you kept it simple please.
Side note: in my `Acpt` button, when I add more than 9 names I get an error even though I added an `else` that should be able to prevent the error. Any tips?

Comment: What a sorted 2D array should look like?

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning for the 2nd dimension of the array?  Is this like first name, last name?  Because I only see on text box.

Comment: For your problem with adding more than 9 names:  Your 10th name does not trigger the outer else because n=2 and m = 2.  It's hitting the inner else.

Comment: In general, as a suggestion, forget multidimensional arrays in .NET . Jagged arrays are OK, but multidimensional array are an unsupported incomplete pain.

Comment: If your assignment allows flexibility, then you can use two arrays instead of a multidimensional array and pass both of them to `Array.Sort(arr1, arr2)`, as one of its overloads allows that.  Although, I must admit I don't fully follow the need of a multidimensional array in this case.. perhaps to track name changes?  There are better datastructures for that, but they may be a bit too advanced for someone new.  You'd have to give us more details.

Comment: yeah you're right I dont need to 2d array, I tried it as 1d and I got it to work. I guess I was trying to do a 2d since we learned that the previous class and I now realize I don't even need it. Sorry about the dumb question guys Edit: I might try that B.K thanks for the help but I think i'll stick to 1d for the moment

Comment: It's not a dumb question.  I admire the fact that you actually gave us some code and that you're trying things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Side Note: in my Acpt button for some reason i'm able to add more than
>   9 names which triggers a error even though I added an else that should
>   be able to prevent that.

```
if (n < 3)
        {
            if (m < 3)
```

It should be n <= 3 and m <= 3

As for the first part of your question.

You can sort the array like so

```
for(int i = 0; i < matrizN.Length; i++)
{
    Array.Sort(matrizN[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < matrizN[i][j]; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(matrizN[i][j]);
    }
}
```

This code will loop through all the elements in each dimension. Sort all the values, then display them. It will do that until all the values are displayed.

**Warning : This code has not been tested so you may have a tweak a few things.**

Edit: I just saw your comment when you stated that you don't need a 2d array. Nonetheless, I'll leave this here for future reference.

Comment: thanks for the help, while I don't need this right now i'll make sure to keep this in mind for future projects. :) I'll just leave this as answered since I got it to work